# JQuery function basic syntax

Tags: jquery

I want to make a jquery function which will be returning a number and I want to use that function somewhere else. please suggest if below is the rigt way of doing it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function print()
{
     var count=1;
     $('#forwardbutton').click(function(){
      count++;
     });

     return count;
  };
</script>
```

Comment: @MohitArora: You *can*, just not like that. :-)

Comment: Then what is alternative? @MohitArora

Comment: You should read this(http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove function since you cannot use click event like the way you are doing

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     var count=1;
     $('#forwardbutton').click(function(){
      count++;

      // your code to use count variable


     });

});
```

Comment: @Rakesh Shetty How will I be able to use this code some where else? I want to give the reference of a function that is returning a number.

Comment: *"since you cannot use click event inside any function"* Sure you can. In fact, you **are**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the `print` function return the number of times that the element has been clicked. Your `print` function will only ever return `1`.

If you want a function that hooks up a click handler and then does something with the number of times the element has been clicked, you can do it by having the function accept a *callback*. (I wouldn't call the function `print`, as there's a global `print` function already, and that can get confusing *really* fast.)

For example:

```
function someNameHere(callback) {
    var count = 0;
    $('#forwardbutton').click(function(){
        ++count;
        callback(count);
    });
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
someNameHere(function(newCount) {
    // ...use `newCount`...
});
```

Note that the function now accepts a callback function,and calls it each time the element is clicked, with the new click count. (I also started the count at `0` rather than `1`.)